# NotSupportedException cloning a Panel control in .NET CF

Tags: c#, compact-framework, clone

in my CF application I use the following code to clone controls:

```
private static T Clone<T>(T controlToClone) 
  where T : Control
{
  try
  {
    PropertyInfo[] controlProperties = typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

    T instance = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();

    foreach (PropertyInfo propInfo in controlProperties)
    {
      if (propInfo.CanWrite)
      {
        if (propInfo.Name != "WindowTarget")
          propInfo.SetValue(instance, propInfo.GetValue(controlToClone, null), null);
      }
    }
    return instance;
  }
  catch (Exception e) { MessageBox.Show(e.InnerException.Message); return null; }
}
```

When I clone a Panel control and the cycle arrives at 'Font' property, I get an exception

> 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' with InnerException:
>   'System.NotSupportedException'.

Why this happen? Is there a way to avoid it?

Comment: You can't clone a Control. It contains an unmanaged Windows Handle (for the control's window) which you just can't copy like that.

Comment: @MatthewWatson is not a real clone, is more a sort of copy. The new control is created and then the properties from the controlToClone are copied.

Comment: Have you stepped it? Figure out which property is throwing the exception. Do you need to check CanRead and not just CanWrite?

Answer (score 1):

I would think any property whose data type is not a value type (or has value-type semantics) should not be copied in this way.  For those kinds of properties, try to implement a deep clone/copy.  Still, there are bound to be some properties that will have to be filtered out.

In regards to the Font, it turns out that the Font class supports `IClonable`, so I also suggest that you test for that and any property whose type supports it should be copied using the `Clone` method.